# Combine rows that have same value in a variable in R

Tags: r

I created the following data frame in R:

```
V1 <- c(1,3,2,6,7,7,5,3,1,1)
V2 <- c("rot", "grün", "grün", "gelb", "blau", "rot", "grün", "blau",    
"blau", "schwarz")
V3 <- c(44,23,28,23,88,88,44,28,11,44)
as.data.frame(cbind(V1,V2,V3) )

   V1      V2 V3
1   1     rot 44
2   3    grün 23
3   2    grün 28
4   6    gelb 23
5   7    blau 88
6   7     rot 88
7   5    grün 44
8   3    blau 28
9   1    blau 11
10  1 schwarz 44
```

V3 is the variable I want to use to rearrange the data set. 
The result should be a data frame that contains a row for each value of V3, and the information on the other variables in the same row.

For this example, what I want is something like that:

```
V3  V1.1  V2.1  V2.1  V2.2  V1.3  V2.3

11  1     blau   NA    NA    NA    NA
23  3     grün    6   gelb   NA    NA
28  2     grün    3   blau   NA    NA
44  1     rot     5   grün    1   schwarz
88  7     blau    7   rot    NA    NA
```

Is there a function that can do that?
Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: It looks like a matter of reshaping data but I do not see a logic underneath the transformation.

Comment: yes, it is some sort of reshaping the data, what I simply want is grouping the data by variable V3 and then the information of V1 and V2 for the specific value of V3 in the same line. Since V1=11 just once the rest of the row is not defined, it could also be empty instead of NA. Does this explain the pattern in a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
reshape(transform(df,time=ave(seq_len(nrow(df)),V3,FUN=seq_along)),dir='w',idvar='V3');
##   V3 V1.1 V2.1 V1.2 V2.2 V1.3    V2.3
## 1 44    1  rot    5 grün    1 schwarz
## 2 23    3 grün    6 gelb <NA>    <NA>
## 3 28    2 grün    3 blau <NA>    <NA>
## 5 88    7 blau    7  rot <NA>    <NA>
## 9 11    1 blau <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table`.

We convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(df1)`).  Create a sequence column 'indx' based on the grouping variable 'V3', and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'.  In the devel version, `dcast` can take multiple `value.var` columns.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, indx:=1:.N, V3]#create sequence variable
dcast(df1, V3~indx, value.var=c('V1', 'V2'), sep=".")
#    V3 V1.1 V1.2 V1.3 V2.1 V2.2    V2.3
#1: 11    1   NA   NA blau   NA      NA
#2: 23    3    6   NA grün gelb      NA
#3: 28    2    3   NA grün blau      NA
#4: 44    1    5    1  rot grün schwarz
#5: 88    7    7   NA blau  rot      NA
```

NOTE: Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

This could be done in a more compact way using `getanID` from `splitstackshape` to create the sequence variable.

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 dcast(getanID(df1, 'V3'), V3~.id, value.var=c('V1', 'V2'))
 #   V3 V1_1 V1_2 V1_3 V2_1 V2_2    V2_3
 #1: 11    1   NA   NA blau   NA      NA
 #2: 23    3    6   NA grün gelb      NA
 #3: 28    2    3   NA grün blau      NA
 #4: 44    1    5    1  rot grün schwarz
 #5: 88    7    7   NA blau  rot      NA
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3)
```